# How do I detect BGP attacks in these Wireshark packets

Tags: wireshark, bgp, attack-vector

I received a Wireshark capture file as a task. There are 3 TCP packets for the TCP 3-way handshake to establish the connection and 4 BGP packets.

I received additional information and now I have to use these 7 packets to find out which BGP attacks occurred and which prefixes were attacked. I've already researched and found out a lot, but I still need a little help.

The additional information: It's about a BGP session between Bob (1.1.1.1 | AS 65100) and Alice (2.2.2.2 | AS 65200). Bob has the prefixes 10.30.0.0/16 and 10.10.0.0/16.

Wireshark .cap File exported as text:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000       1.1.1.1               2.2.2.2               TCP      60     46612 → 179 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=16384 Len=0 MSS=536

Frame 1: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface unknown, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: c2:00:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:00:1e:8c:00:00), Dst: c2:01:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:01:1e:8c:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 1.1.1.1, Dst: 2.2.2.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 46612, Dst Port: 179, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 2.016208       2.2.2.2               1.1.1.1               TCP      60     179 → 46612 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=16384 Len=0 MSS=536

Frame 2: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface unknown, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: c2:01:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:01:1e:8c:00:00), Dst: c2:00:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:00:1e:8c:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2.2.2.2, Dst: 1.1.1.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 179, Dst Port: 46612, Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 2.024158       1.1.1.1               2.2.2.2               TCP      60     46612 → 179 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=16384 Len=0

Frame 3: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface unknown, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: c2:00:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:00:1e:8c:00:00), Dst: c2:01:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:01:1e:8c:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 1.1.1.1, Dst: 2.2.2.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 46612, Dst Port: 179, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2.032159       1.1.1.1               2.2.2.2               BGP      99     OPEN Message

Frame 4: 99 bytes on wire (792 bits), 99 bytes captured (792 bits) on interface unknown, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: c2:00:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:00:1e:8c:00:00), Dst: c2:01:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:01:1e:8c:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 1.1.1.1, Dst: 2.2.2.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 46612, Dst Port: 179, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 45
Border Gateway Protocol - OPEN Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 2.040180       2.2.2.2               1.1.1.1               BGP      118    OPEN Message, KEEPALIVE Message

Frame 5: 118 bytes on wire (944 bits), 118 bytes captured (944 bits) on interface unknown, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: c2:01:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:01:1e:8c:00:00), Dst: c2:00:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:00:1e:8c:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 2.2.2.2, Dst: 1.1.1.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 179, Dst Port: 46612, Seq: 1, Ack: 46, Len: 64
Border Gateway Protocol - OPEN Message
Border Gateway Protocol - KEEPALIVE Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 2.048158       1.1.1.1               2.2.2.2               BGP      73     KEEPALIVE Message

Frame 6: 73 bytes on wire (584 bits), 73 bytes captured (584 bits) on interface unknown, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: c2:00:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:00:1e:8c:00:00), Dst: c2:01:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:01:1e:8c:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 1.1.1.1, Dst: 2.2.2.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 46612, Dst Port: 179, Seq: 46, Ack: 65, Len: 19
Border Gateway Protocol - KEEPALIVE Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 2.056158       1.1.1.1               2.2.2.2               BGP      323    UPDATE Message, UPDATE Message, UPDATE Message, UPDATE Message, UPDATE Message

Frame 7: 323 bytes on wire (2584 bits), 323 bytes captured (2584 bits) on interface unknown, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: c2:00:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:00:1e:8c:00:00), Dst: c2:01:1e:8c:00:00 (c2:01:1e:8c:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 1.1.1.1, Dst: 2.2.2.2
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 46612, Dst Port: 179, Seq: 65, Ack: 65, Len: 269
Border Gateway Protocol - UPDATE Message
Border Gateway Protocol - UPDATE Message
Border Gateway Protocol - UPDATE Message
Border Gateway Protocol - UPDATE Message
Border Gateway Protocol - UPDATE Message
```

I couldn't find anything in the 3 TCP packets and the BGP open messages and BGP keep-alives. However, I was able to create a table from the 5 BGP update messages and find a few discrepancies.

```
AS PATH     | NEXT HOP | NLRI           | ORIGIN
----------------------------------------------------
65100       | 1.1.1.1  | 10.10.1.0/24   | IGP
            |          | 10.10.2.0/24   |
            |          | 10.10.3.0/24   |
----------------------------------------------------
65100       | 1.1.1.1  | 172.16.0.0/30  | Incomplete
            |          | 172.16.0.4/30  |
----------------------------------------------------
65300 65100 | 1.1.1.1  | 10.30.1.0/24   | IGP
            |          | 10.30.2.0/24   |
            |          | 10.30.3.0/24   |
----------------------------------------------------
65100 65300 | 1.1.1.1  | 172.16.0.8/30  | Incomplete
----------------------------------------------------
65300 65100 | 1.1.1.1  | 172.16.0.12/30 | Incomplete
```

The 1st and 3rd update messages look neat to me because of the IGP and NRLIs owned by Bob. So I assume that BGP attacks took place in the other 3 update messages because the origin is incomplete and the NRLIs don't belong to Bob.

If I'm hopefully correct so far, my question now is: What attacks have taken place here and how can you tell? I once heard the terms prefix hijacking, subprefix hijacking and route leaks. But how I can recognize them was never explained to me, and I didn't really learn much about them on the Internet.

Comment: Can someone help me please :(